Correct cURL format to send push notifications to Mozilla
I am trying to figure out the correct format of cURL request to Mozilla endpoint url for push notifications but I am giving up.. I am getting error with HTTP code: 400 which is "bad request" and can not understand what I am missing. A lack of information regarding the php option to send requests directly to the user endpoint url and maybe one of you had this problem and will share his experience regarding this issue.. Here is my php code:
$subscription = [
    'endpoint' => 'https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v2/gAAAAABmzIip-iAcvn_g_o6eozX5RHOx-sHSKwWC8jDlupllbqSp0Rx79PvC98rR8RDBlEnYJNwBbdfT8Y6sNbguUELQJN004HS6Zlei3liawWeOvuvrOZ3iFas454yVz2309sjo0AambY_xDwbT3_DMksEYEYfalg2_0qsclERpI3vxUhekULw',
    'keys' => [
        'p256dh' => 'BEfhmTqDfYiuz9X708IQp3EF04JjFYEa8NZ2sG8K1m7mXxjNorfpHBBcmlS26jYC3Tz0BA7gp1mE........',
        'auth' => 'SArepOvQdGABbEq1N.....',
    ]
];

$payload = json_encode([
    'title' => 'New Notification',
    'body' => 'This is a test notification from Web Site Maker',
]);



$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'TTL: 60',
    $subscription
];

$options = [
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0, 
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
];

$ch = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$error = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if ($error) {
    echo "Error: $error";
} else {
    if ($httpCode != 201) {
        echo "Notification failed with HTTP code: $httpCode";
    } else {
        echo "Notification sent successfully! Payload: $payload";
    }
}

I will highly appreciate your time and suggestions !
Thanks
PS
Link to error code documentation:
https://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes
LInk to web push international standards:
https://webpush-wg.github.io/webpush-encryption/simple_base/
//new cURL looks like:
$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'TTL: 86400',
    'Topic: new_mail',
    'Authorization: '.$publicVapidKey
];

$options = [
CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

and returns the following error:
Response:
{"code":401,"errno":109,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Missing VAPID token","more_info":"http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes"}


Please add a link to the documentation.

https://mozilla-services.github.io/autopush-rs/ should be the correct documentation. The one you've linked to says it's obsolete

Anyway since you said you got a 400 error, which sub-error did you receive? You may need to output the response body to see it. As per https://mozilla-services.github.io/autopush-rs/errors.html that should give you more specific information about what was wrong with your request.

I made some changes according to the docs in the link provided and now the response is:
Response: {"code":401,"errno":109,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Missing VAPID token","more_info":"http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes"}
the new cURL:
is posted below PS

ok thanks. Looking at your new code, we can't see what you've put into $publicVapidKey, so maybe it doesn't contain the right value, or it's not in the right format.

$publicVapidKey contains correct vapid key which is used in JS version of push notification. For some reasons I need to make it work (to send user notifications) with php cURL directly to his endpoint.. I double checked above auth, vapid key if they are correct.. You mentioned the format of vapid key - this is how it looks like:
$publicVapidKey = 'BOzdJ4aWDSZPeDcUZmapdwN5wcrZkOzzS238W0djUC7LJQKV1dK35WPFHDpbIGWm1J4fB-ppeWRQyT2IfC_7n-s';//this is my app VAPID key

Thanks. The documentation you provided doesn't mention it at all, but the link I found, which seems to be more recent, https://mozilla-services.github.io/autopush-rs/http.html#message-topics mentions an example of the Vapid key header looking like this: "Authorization: Vapid AbCd..." whereas your code would produce a header like this: "Authorization: AbCd...". Neither documentation is particularly clear or informative, I have to say, but it's worth trying to change your PHP code to adapt to that suggested format, I think.

i.e. $headers = [     'Content-Type: application/json',     'TTL: 86400',     'Topic: new_mail',     'Authorization: Vapid '.$publicVapidKey ];, I was thinking you should do this

@ADyson, thanks for your time first of all !
I think we are close to make it happen :) I tested what you suggested and there is slight difference in the responce regardless the error code is always 401 / sub error 109, but the error message is different in both tests..
For header:
$headers = ['Content-Type: application/json','TTL: 86400','Topic: new_mail','Authorization: '.$publicVapidKey];
//Response: {"code":401,"errno":109,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Missing VAPID token","more_info":"http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes"}

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@ADyson I invited you to chat and if we succeed you can post it as answer, right?
